# Nginx Domain scheme redirect excluding subdomain

Tags: nginx, dns, subdomain, cname

Lets assume I have a domain called example.com along with the following 'n' number of subdomains all of them with 'A' record to same IP address(Assume Server A).

a.example.com,b.example.com,c.example.com ... z.example.com

There is another subdomain 'email.example.com' with CNAME set to 'mailgun.org'.

Now I have Server A with the following nginx configuration wherein I want to forward all HTTP requests to HTTPS.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

And set of code blocks to handle individual sub domain requests to 443.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  a.example.com;
    //SSL Details
    location / {
            root /var/www/a/;
    }
```

Similarly for rest of the sub domains except email.example.com which points to mailgun.org.

Now,
http://email.example.com they will be redirected to http://mailgun.com. (At DNS level)

http://example.com they will be redirected to https://example.com. (At Server level).

http://a.example.com they will be redirected to https://a.example.com. (At server level)

Problem:
After visiting to http://example.com, when someone tries to visit http://email.example.com they are being redirected to https://email.example.com by browser. Since I have no control over mailgun.org, I can handle https requests for email.example.com

Is there anyway to set nginx config where in every request to HTTP will be redirected to HTTPS except email.example.com?

Comment: What you describe sounds rather improbable - the issue with http:// email.example.com appears to be occurring in the browser or in DNS - hence nginx configuration has nothing to do with it. I suggest your first course of action is to try to identify empirically what DNS / the browser / nginx are actually doing.

Comment: Firstly, there is no redirection "at DNS level". Secondly, what *SSL details* do you use? Is there an HSTS header?

Comment: @symcbean Exactly., How do I tell the browser not to redirect http:// email.example.com to https?

When I visit http://example.com its redirecting to https://example.com, but after that browsers are redirecting even email.example.com to https.

Comment: @RichardSmith When I meant "at DNS level" I was talking about CNAME record. I'm using rapidSSL wildcard SSL. I've set "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" in nginx.

Comment: There is your problem. Your HSTS header instructs the **browser** to use `https://email.example.com`. If you *must* use `http` on your subdomain, you will need to remove `includeSubDomains` and wait 31536000 seconds ;-)

Comment: What HSTS header?

Comment: @Karthik: I suspect that you're not telling us the full story here - 301 redirects are inherently dangerous and should **never** be used until you know everything is working as it should with 302s. Your first step should be to find out what headers you get back when requesting http:// email.example.com

Comment: @symcbean Thank you helping out., I had set add_header for example.com in nginx server block to includeSubDomains. Coming to 301 redirect., that is what I wanted to move all http to https permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

I changed my nginx configuration for example.com to not to include subdomains.

ie., Changed the following line

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
```

as below.,

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;" always;
```

So that browsers now don't add header to sub domains.