# Point sub domain to another domain on another server

Tags: apache, nginx, dns, vhosts, wildcard-subdomain

is it possible to point my `example.com` domain to another domain like

`example2.com` on another server ?

my idea is to point

`{variable}.example.com` to `example2.com/{variable}`

like

```
A.example.com -> someoneElseServer.com/A
B.example.com -> someoneElseServer.com/B
C.example.com -> someoneElseServer.com/C
```

I own `A.example.com` but `someoneElseServer.com/A` is on another server and it's not mine , it's just a service that I need to use it somehow by changing the variable which is {A,B,C} and keep in mind that {A,B,C} are wildcard sub domains and it can be anything

I'm happy to do that on nginx , apache or maybe any other suggestion like domain configuration on the host itself or anything.

note : I need to point domain , not redirect

As I know it's possible to connect domain to another server or domain but I care now about the variable to be in the sub domain

any idea or suggestion to solve that ?

Edit:

I saw this solution

[Pointing sub-domain to another domain on another host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827261/pointing-sub-domain-to-another-domain-on-another-host)

but my problem is to make it dynamic subdomain . not static

Comment: "is it possible to point my example.com domain to another domain like" No, not just with the DNS you need a webserver configured as reverse proxy or doing redirection. But your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: I don't think this is off topic at all :). he did it in the right place ,  you want me to share with you some ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824748/nginx-domain-scheme-redirect-excluding-subdomain?rq=1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633590/how-to-match-dynamic-sub-domain-alias-to-sub-folder-on-apache-server
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388618/redirect-all-wildcard-subdomains-to-root-domain?noredirect=1&lq=1
let me know if you want more link @PatrickMevzek  .

Comment: @badraldeen The fact that there are previous questions offtopic does not make this one magically on topic. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic